# Vulnerability in Apache 2.4.12 Wiley 5.10

Tags: apache2, security, 15.10

Security scan revealed following vulnerabilities in fully patched and updated 5.10 Wiley distro:

CVE-2015-0253
CVE-2015-0228
CVE-2015-3185

Apache Security confirm 2.4.12 is vulnerable [here](https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html).

Question is, what is the best way to mitigate these vulnerabilities and will the repos ever have the new 2.4.16 apache available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should already have the most up-to-date version available through the official repositories.

However, you *can* use an external repository that provides newer releases. [This Launchpad PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2?field.series_filter=wily) has all the way up to 2.4.17 available for Wily (15.10).

You can add it via

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you still don't have the newer version of Apache2, try running `sudo apt-get install dist-upgrade`.

After all of these are run, you should have the updated (and thus patched) version of Apache2!

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing the update through the official repositories and nothing came up:                                                                                     
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$ apache2ctl -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu)

I guess what I'm asking for is when will it be available through the official repositories?

Comment: Checked the Link listed for Launchpad PPA given and there are two words which stand out and make me nervous... "unsupported" and "untrusted". Is there another "supported" path I can follow as this is a production server?

Comment: @YouDontNeedMyName The only reason that they say that is to differentiate it from the official repositories. Many people have recommended and/or use that repository, the PPA just provides the updates from the Debian Apache2 in an easy-to-access form.